# Update based on select to same table with group by

Tags: mysql

I want to update all the distinct values inside the table

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `coumn1` = 1 WHERE `ID` IN (
SELECT `ID` FROM `table1` group by `column2`
)
```

Original

```
Column1   | Column2
-------------------
0         | 2
0         | 3
0         | 2
0         | 4
0         | 5
```

Result

```
Column1   | Column2
-------------------
1         | 2
1         | 3
0         | 2
1         | 4
1         | 5
```

Comment: What is "ID" ? Is it another column?

Comment: `coumn1`? Who ate the L?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do an `UPDATE` to a table that is also used in a `SELECT` subquery, because of the risk of recursion.